# Laravel + Vue two same Projects but one CSRF Error

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

i have 2 projects where the the laravel base code is the same but the in the one project the vue.js part is more advanced.
Now i have a strange error message in the javascript console.

```
CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token
```

In my next step i copied the older version of the functional vue code but the same error.
The code that i copied worked in the other project

The bootstrap code is the same and looks like this:

```
window._ = require('lodash');

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap-sass');
} catch (e) {}

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Next we will register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

Than i make some test's in the bootstrap.js code like this:

```
console.log(token);
```

The result is empty.

What i can do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set it first in the `meta` tag of the html hearder :

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Comment: Yes. If it would be not set the other project would not work

Answer (score 0):

try using `window.token` instead of `token`